# Shapeless: batch update using Record

Tags: scala, shapeless, case-class

I have a need for modifying multiple fields of a case class without all the `copy` code. Seems shapeless is a good way to go.

According to [example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/lenses.scala), I could use `lens` in this form:

`lensA ~ lensB ~ lensC set(something)(valA, valB, valC)`

which is good. However in my case, nested fields are not my biggest concern (I'm sure it will :-< ). So the `lens` solution is pretty much the same as:

`something.copy(a = valA, b = valB, c = valC)`

One thing I'd like to point out is that, not all the modifications are necessarily happened. In my pseudo case, I may update all `a,b,c` or some of them, or none, based on some `if/else`s within the context.

Therefore, `Record` with this kind of usage is pretty much what I need:

`someHList + ('a ->> valA) + ('b ->> valB) + ('c ->> valC)`

Even ultimately:

```
Seq(
  'a ->> valA, 
  'b ->> valB,
  'c ->> valC
).fold(someHList)(_ + _)
```

which is not possible according to my compiler (yield type mismatch error).

I know this usage only exists in my imagination, not documentation. However I'd really appreciate the correct way of using `Record` or `lens` or whatever to solve my problem. Any other elegant way is also welcomed!

THX!

Comment: Have you looked at the [case classes a la carte](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/alacarte.scala) example?

Comment: @MilesSabin thanks for your quick reply! Shapeless rocks! However I'm lost here. In a la carte example, I could only get a non case class mimic case class. What should I do with it to update an existing case class instance? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already [update single field operation `+`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/8a79c4302baca9b7f7c9a56cb4d33f19c0214d16/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/records.scala#L76) via the [Updater](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/8a79c4302baca9b7f7c9a56cb4d33f19c0214d16/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/records.scala#L96) operation provider and only thing you need is to apply it via  [some fold operation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/8a79c4302baca9b7f7c9a56cb4d33f19c0214d16/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L372)

So you can write

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftFolder
import shapeless.ops.record.Updater
import syntax.singleton._
import record._

object updateAll extends Poly2 {
  implicit def updateOne[L <: HList, F](implicit update: Updater[L, F]) = at[L, F]((l, f) => update(l, f))
}

implicit class UpdateAllOps[L <: HList](record: L) {
  def ++>[U <: HList](updates: U)(implicit fl: LeftFolder[U, L, updateAll.type]): fl.Out =
    fl(updates, record)
}
```

now having

```
val rec = 'x ->> "Old" :: 'y ->> 1 :: HNil
val upd = 'z ->> true :: 'x ->> "New" :: HNil
```

You can verify that

```
rec ++> upd
```

Is same that

```
'x ->> "New" :: 'y ->> 1 :: 'z ->> true :: HNil
```

But important note that

```
val str = "New".asInstanceOf[String with Serializable]
rec ++> ('x ->> str :: HNil)
```

will result in something like

```
'x ->> "Old" :: y ->> 1 :: 'x -> "New" :: HNil
```

so you should be very careful with your types here, unless you define your own replacement for `Updater`

Comment: Thanks @Odomontois ! It just works. I really need to spend some time to take shapeless 101.